# How to return failed task result in continuation task?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, google-tasks-api

I am using Google's Task API in Kotlin and am faced with the next situation:

```
...
val deleteTask = getItem(id)?.continueWithTask { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful)
        task.result?.toObject(ItemModel::class.java)?.let { deleteFiles(it.media) }
}

deleteTask?.continueWithTask { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) doSomething()
} ?: doSomething()
...
```

Where `getItem(id)` returns the `Firebase.firestore` get task (`Task<DocumentSnapshot>?`) and `deleteFiles(it.media)` returns the `Firebase.storage` delete task (`Task<Void>?`). `doSomething()` should be called if either: the delete task succeed or no delete was needed at all (`deleteFiles(it.media)` would return null).

The problem is when the get task fails: In that case, I would like the `deleteTask` to be a non-null Task (as null is a valid case for me as explained) with `isSuccessful = false` (so `doSomething()` won't be called), but I couldn't find a way to create a dummy failed task. I thought about returning the get task (`if (task.isSuccessful) ... else task`), but it gives a "Type mismatch" error (which makes sense as `Task<DocumentSnapshot>?` and `Task<Void>?` are different types...).

So, How can I return a failed task result in a continuation task?

(For more information on why I need this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65744647/how-to-return-failed-task-result-in-continuation-task) I explained my specific case with more details, but as I understood from the answer I got there, the details only distract from the question...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found what I've been looking for:
Tasks API has a `Tasks` object which has functions: `forCanceled()` & `forResult()`. Before I only investigated the `Task` class and didn't know of the `Tasks` object... For more information, see [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks).